# cache eval() result

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, is it possible to cache the results of [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)?

For example it would be great if I could:

```
var str="some code...";
var code = eval(str);
//later on...
code.reExecute();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make `str` the body of a function and use `New Function` instead of `eval`.

```
var fn = new Function([param1, param2,...], str);
```

And reuse it by calling `fn(p1, p2,...)`

Or use eval, and make `str` be something like

```
var fn = eval("(function(a){alert(a);})")
```

Comment: This. Although it's slightly different to `eval` in that the code in the string does not inherit the local scope of the containing code.

Comment: It seems like both answers use ALMOST the same way to do it, great!is there any performance benchamark which exact method (1- creating new function with a string, 2- eval a function) is better?

Comment: I moved from eval to new Function in the first release of a JS lib I did(PURE) and did not notice any performance improvement. However the comment of bobince is the one that needs to drive your choice, if the parameters you pass to the function are always the same, you can use New Function otherwise use eval. Are you sure you want to use eval? In the current version of PURE, by trying harder, we suppressed both evil methods. Ok... this is another debate :)

Answer (score 1):

The result of the 'eval' call is to evaluate the javascript. Javascript (in browsers) does not offer any kind of 'compile' function.

The closest you could get (using eval) is:

```
var cached_func = eval('function() {' + str + '}');
```

Then you can call the `cached_func` later.

Comment: See [here](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/get_started.html) for an example of using `Script::Compile` with Google's V8 JavaScript engine.

Answer (score 1):

Make a function that evaluates and stores the result in a cache object for asynchronous retrieval:

```
 var Cache = { } ;

 function evalString(string) {

     var evaluated = eval(string) ;
         Cache.evalResult = evaluated ;

 }
```

You may then call that code like this:

```
 Cache.evalResult(/* arguments */) ;
```

---

On a side note, "eval is evil" as http://www.jslint.com will tell you, since it may open the door for external manipulation of your content. Why do you need to `eval` that function it in the first place?